# How to work out which drive and directory your system booted from if it is not mounted in /etc/fstab?

Tags: boot, partition, devices, fstab

My `/etc/fstab` doesn't include the disk the system booted from, basically because I made some changes and forgot to include this. The initial `/boot` and `/` directories are on different drives.

I noticed this because when I upgrade the system and grub and kernel get updated the changes are made to the `/boot` directory under `/` which is not initial boot drive.

How can I tell after boot with device was booted from and its directory?

I want to mount it in `/etc/fstab` as `/boot` and delete or rename the `boot` directory under `/` to something else.

Comment: I am hoping that are more experienced use can suggest a proper substitute for the '/etc/fstab' tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root filesystem is passed to the kernel upon boot using the `root` argument. So you should be able to:

```
cat /proc/cmdline
```

and then look for `root=/some/path`, or perhaps `root=UUID=longstring`. For instance, I get:

```
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/kernel-genkernel-x86_64-4.4.0-sabayon root=UUID=18f3b5a1-3994-43ef-ad6d-cb4c86ff5f95 ro quiet splash
```

If it's a path, it should point to something recognizable (like /dev/sdb3). If it's a UUID, copy the UUID, and run:

```
ls -la /dev/disk/by-uuid/[paste UUID here]
```

That should point to a symlink, like:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 11 22:14 /dev/disk/by-uuid/06699502-fc90-48e4-86c2-cefdaf921e41 -> ../../sda4
```

Which should tell you which drive it was (in my case, the 4th partition of sda, iow, /dev/sda4)

Comment: My original belief was right. There are two `grub.cfg` files on the system. The upgrade routine updates the wrong one because the drive holding it is not mounted in `/etc/fstab`. So I will have to mount it in `/etc/fstab` or change the boot disk in the BIOS  that will fix it.